# how to fix query mysql with multiple sum

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a query data from sum function:

```
ROUND(((nominal)*12) * ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2)/100,2) AS nominal_persentasi,
ROUND((((nominal)*12) * ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2))*(1.1/100)/100,2) AS tambah_persentasi,
ROUND((((nominal)*12) *  ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2))+((((nominal)*12) *  ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2))*(1.1/100))/100,2) AS total_penyesuaian
```

And the results are:

```
nominal_persentasi | tambah_persentasi | total_penyesuaian
12.000               3.000               1.203.000
```

The results produced should be 15,000 , why did it happen ?

I tried to sum the variable `nominal_persentasi + tambah_persentasi` but the result is `0`.

Comment: `the results produced should be 15,000` ... which results?

Comment: 12.000 + 3.000 = 15.000 right?

Comment: i mean my result is not 15.000 but 1.203.000 it look like combine first data and second data not sum the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a division by `100` in your total.  Hence, instead of adding `12,000` and `3,000` to get `15,000` you were actually adding `12,000,000` and `3,000` to get `12,003,000`.

```
SELECT ROUND(( (nominal)*12) *  ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2)/100,2) AS nominal_persentasi,
       ROUND((((nominal)*12) *  ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2))*(1.1/100)/100,2) AS tambah_persentasi,
       ROUND((((nominal)*12) *  ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2)/100) + ((((nominal)*12) *  ROUND((SUM((a.NCI)/3*(60/100))+SUM((b.NSI)/3*(40/100)))/3,2))*(1.1/100))/100, 2) AS total_penyesuaian
FROM yourTable                      -- your query was missing this division by 100           ^^^
```

Comment: okay...so what i must do? should i use decimal or i must fix the query?I have tried to use decimal in that query but the result is 0

Comment: I just fixed your query, cut and paste what I gave above.  Or, better yet, just cut and paste verbatim the expressions for the two columns in the sum.  You removed a division by 100 which appeared in the `nominal_persentasi` column.

Comment: Nice catch Tim. #EagleEye